# python subprocess error calling java class

Tags: java, python, subprocess

I'm trying to run a java class from a python script with `subprocess.call()`:

```
import os
import subprocess

java_file = os.getcwd() + "/src/ch/idsia/scenarios/Main.java"
if os.path.isfile(java_file):
  java_class, _ = os.path.splitext(java_file)
  cmd = ['java', java_class]
  subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
```

But running this python script gives me `Error: Could not find or load main class .Users.alavin.Code.MarioAI_ver02_April_2011.src.ch.idsia.scenarios.Main`. I've also tried the following variations for `java_class`:
`"Users.alavin.Code.MarioAI_ver02_April_2011.src.ch.idsia.scenarios.Main"`
`"src.ch.idsia.scenarios.Main"`

The python script is located in "Users/alavin/Code/MarioAI_ver02_April_2011/". The java class is "Main.java" in package "src.ch.idsia.scenarios". The java project is in Eclipse.

Notes: mac osx 10.9; python 2.7; java 1.7; using jython is not an option; running `echo $CLASSPATH` from the terminal gives a blank line.

Thank you in advance for any help/guidance.

Comment: Isn't it a matter of setting the class path appropriately?

Comment: Read up what classpath is. Make sure `Main.class` is present in `/Users/alavin/Code/MarioAI_ver02_April_2011/src/ch/idsia/scenarios/`

Comment: @thekashyap `Main.class` is in `/Users/alavin/Code/MarioAI_ver02_April_2011/bin/ch/idsia/scenarios/`.
I.e. the `.java` files in the 'src/' directory have their corresponding `.class` files in the `bin/` directory. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classpath was the issue; I needed to include the jar files in the call from the terminal: `java -cp bin/MarioAI/:lib/asm-all-3.3.jar:lib/jdom.jar ch.idsia.scenarios.Main`. So running the subprocess command in python would be:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['java', '-cp', 'bin/MarioAI/:lib/asm-all-3.3.jar:lib/jdom.jar', 'ch.idsia.scenarios.Main']
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
```

To check the jar files in the classpath via Eclipse: right click Main.java -> Run Configurations -> Classpath tab.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `-cp` option to specify the class path, e.g.

```
java -cp /Users/alavin/Code/MarioAI_ver02_April_2011/src/ch/idsia/scenarios Main
```

So,

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-cp', '/Users/alavin/Code/MarioAI_ver02_April_2011/src/ch/idsia/scenarios', 'Main'])
```

**Edit**

Since Main is in package `src.ch.idsia.scenarios` try amending the command to:

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-cp', '/Users/alavin/Code/MarioAI_ver02_April_2011', 'src.ch.idsia.scenarios.Main'])
```

Comment: I still get `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`.

Comment: Try the revised command. Try running it on the command line to help diagnose any problems.

Comment: Same error, and running from the command line only returns the value 1.

I also tried adding the java program root directory to the python system path with `sys.path.append('/Users/alavin/Code/MarioAI_ver02_April_2011')`, but still the same error.

Comment: Is `1` the expected output? If not then you need to figure out exactly how to run the Java program from the command line and then put that same command into your Python code.

Comment: `0` is the expected output. Could you please advise how I can run correctly from the command line? I think the issue is with either my CLASSPATH or python system path, or both.